# PHP - If value equals

Tags: php, magento, if-statement

I have a php related question about the if statement. I have this piece of code:

```
<?php if(count($targetValue) > 0 ): ?>
    <?php foreach($targetValue as $key=>$val): ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $key ?>">
            <span>
                <?php echo $val ?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

The $val can return up to 10 different values that are pre-defined. I need to know how to check if a value equals a word, then show this.

Example: If $val == "Pinda" then show X. After that, if $val == "Mosterd" then show Y.

For every option that $val returns I want to show a different image.

Regards

UPDATE:

I have this code now:

```
<?php $targetValue = explode(",", $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('nf_allergie')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)); ?>

            <?php if(count($targetValue) > 1 ): ?>
                <?php foreach($targetValue as $key=>$val): ?>
                    <div class="<?php echo $key ?>">
                        <span>
                            <?php
                                switch($val){
                                    CASE "Ei":
                                        echo 'X';
                                        break;
                                    CASE "Gluten":
                                        echo 'X';
                                        break;
                                    CASE "Lupine":
                                        echo 'X';
                                        break;
                                    CASE "Melk, inclusief lactose":
                                        echo 'X';
                                        break;
                                    CASE "Mosterd":
                                        echo 'X';
                                        break;
                                    CASE "Noten":
                                        echo 'X';
                                        break;
                                    CASE "Pinda":
                                        echo 'X';
                                        break;
                                    CASE "Schaaldieren":
                                        echo 'X';
                                        break;
                                    CASE "Selderij":
                                        echo 'X';
                                        break;
                                    CASE "Sesamzaad":
                                        echo 'X';
                                        break;
                                    CASE "Soja":
                                        echo 'X';
                                        break;
                                    CASE "Sulfiet":
                                        echo 'X';
                                        break;
                                    CASE "Vis":
                                        echo 'X';
                                        break;
                                    CASE "Weekdieren":
                                        echo 'X';
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        echo "Leeg";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif;?>
```

But only the first result that will be returned with the X, looks like the foreach doesn't works good?

This is what it returns:
[image: The ones with Name: in front of it are the actual results to check if it works]

The ones with Name: in front of it are the actual results to check if it works

Comment: And whats your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can't get it to work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
$possibleValues = array(

    1 => "Mosterd",
    2 => "Pinda",
    3 => "Cookie"

);

//add more items to the array as you please

foreach($targetValue as $key => $val ) {

    //return the value of the value associated with the key

    echo $possibleValues[$key];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary operator

```
  <?php if(count($targetValue) > 0 ): ?>
    <?php foreach($targetValue as $key=>$val): ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $key ?>">
            <span>
                <?php echo (($val== 'pinda') ?  'X' :  $val) ;?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endif;?>
```

if you have more values you can use a switch

```
 <?php if(count($targetValue) > 0 ): ?>
    <?php foreach($targetValue as $key=>$val): ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $key ?>">
            <span>
                switch($val){
                  CASE 'Pinda': 
                    echo 'X';
                    break;
                  CASE 'Mosterd': 
                    echo 'Y';
                    break;                  
                  CASE 'Salad': 
                    echo 'Z';
                    break;   
                  DEFAULT:
                    echo $val;
                    break 
                }
                <?php echo (($val== 'pinda') ?  'X' :  $val) ;?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks, and how can i do that for all the returning values? For example, $val returns the following values: Pinda, Mosterd, Salad, Bread. Then I want to show a Pinda image, a Mosterd image, a Salad image and a Bread image. Do I need to make multiple foreach or can this be done in one?

Comment: You missed  the last  break at the end of default case  .. and i have update my answer so i think is more clear ..and the foreach seems a new question to me ..